# What is the correct way to loop through an HTML Collection

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to make a slider, and while the code below to calculate the widths of the slides works, it throws an error in the console. What is the correct way to loop through and a width to these elements?

Javascript

```
var calcSlideWidth = function(divId){
    let slDiv = document.getElementById(divId);
    let slides = slDiv.getElementsByClassName('slide');
    slDiv.style = "width:"+ 100*slides.length +"%";
    slideWidth = 100/slides.length;
    for (let i = 0; i <= slides.length; i++ ){
        slides[i].style = " width:"+ slideWidth +"%";
        console.log(i);
    }
}   

window.onload  = function(){
   calcSlideWidth("slider");
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <ul id="slider">
        <li class="slide"><span>Slide 1</span></li>
        <li class="slide"><span>Slide 2</span></li>
        <li class="slide"><span>Slide 3</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: When I opened the console. It would say "TypeError: slides[i] is undefined"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error for sure is the access at position `length`

```
let i = 0; i <= slides.length
              ^
```

That condition will access to a none existing position, so you need to use this:

```
let i = 0; i < slides.length
             ^
```

That way, the access will be from `0` until `length - 1`

Answer (score 4):

The getElementsBy* methods return HTMLCollections, which can be difficult to work with. Consider using querySelectorAll instead, which returns a static NodeList - unlike an HTMLCollection, it can be iterated over directly, it won't change while it's being iterated over, and it's much more flexible.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.slide').forEach(slide => {
  // do stuff with each slide
  slide.style.width = `${slideWidth}%`;
});
```

`for` loops fail to clearly signal the intention of your code, and as such should be avoided whenever possible (prefer higher-order functions, such as .map, .reduce, .filter, ...). See also: http://qr.ae/RNMEGA and https://gist.github.com/robotlolita/7643014

(you'll never have an off-by-one error through `.forEach`)

Note that NodeList.forEach is a new-ish method that some older browsers don't support - if you use this method, make sure to polyfill properly before distribution.

Comment: Just a small addition to NodeList: Older Internet Explorer versions don't come with `forEach` support on NodeLists. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList.

Comment: As @custi mentioned, you need to workaround this using, for example, the prototype `Array.prototype.forEach(nodelist, calllback)`

Comment: @Ele which is, ironically, also not supported by older IE versions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: @custi—you also can't do `[].splice.call(NodeList).forEach(...)` as some versions of IE (I've forgotten which) also barf when a built-in function is passed a host object as *this*. :-(

Comment: @custi That's what the build process should take care of (Babel, polyfills, etc)

Comment: @CertainPerformance put that comment into the answer because is useful for the OP and for the community.

Comment: @CertainPerformance that is true but not every project has a build process. OPs code looks like he is just doing some scripting inside a html file.